# How to substitude outside of regexp matches in a Ruby string?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

Given an example input like below:

```
s = "an example with 'one' word and 'two and three' words inside quotes"
```

I'm trying to iterate over parts outside of quotes to do some substitutions. For example to convert `and` to `&` but only outside of quotes to get:

```
an example with 'one' word & 'two and three' words inside quotes
```

If I were to change **inside** of quotes, I could simply do the following:

```
s.gsub(/'.*?'/){ |q| q.gsub(/and/, '&') }
```

to get:

```
an example with 'one' word and 'two & three' words inside quotes
```

I mainly tried two things to adapt this strategy to **outside** of quotes.

First, I tried to negate the regexp inside first `gsub` (i.e. `/'.*?'/`). I imagine if there were a suffix modifier like `/v` I could simply do `s.gsub(/'.*?'/v){ ... }`, unfortunately I couldn't find anything like this. There is a negative lookahead (i.e. `(?!pat)`) but I don't think it is what I need.

Second, I tried to use `split` with `gsub!` as such:

```
puts s.split(/'.*?'/){ |r| r.gsub!(/and/, '&') }
```

Using `split` I can iterate over the parts outside of quotes:

```
s.split(/'.*?'/){ |r| puts r }
```

to get:

```
an example with 
 word and 
 words inside quotes
```

However, I can't mutate these parts inside the block with `gsub` or `gsub!`. I guess I need a mutating version of `split`, something akin to `gsub` being a mutating version of `scan`, but there doesn't seem to be anything like this.

Is there an easy way to make either of these approaches work?

Answer (score 1):

You may match and capture what you need to keep and just match what you need to replace.

Use

```
s.gsub(/('[^']*')|and/) { $1 || '&' }
s.gsub(/('[^']*')|and/) { |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : '&' }
```

If you need to match `and` as a whole word, use `\band\b` in the pattern instead of `and`.

This approach is very convenient since you may add as many specific patterns you want to *skip* as you want. E.g. you want to also avoid matching a whole word `and` in between double quotation marks:

```
s.gsub(/('[^']*'|"[^"]*")|\band\b/) { $1 || '&' }
```

Or, you want to make sure it is also skipping strings between quotes with escaped quotes:

```
s.gsub(/('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|\band\b/m) { $1 || '&' }
```

Or, if it appears outside of round, square, angle brackets and braces:

```
s.gsub(/(<[^<>]*>|\{[^{}]*\}|\([^()]*\)|\[[^\]\[]*\])|\band\b/m) { $1 || '&' }
```

Match and capture substrings between single quotes and just match what you need to change. If Group 1 matches, put it back with `$1`, else, replace with `&`. The replacement block in the second line just checks if the Group 1 value of the last match is the same as the currently matched value, and if yes, it puts it back, else, replaces with `&`.

See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/wgnKjg).

**Regex details**

- `('[^']*')` - Capturing group #1: `'`, zero or more chars other than `'` and then a `'` char
- `|` - or
- `and` - `and` substring.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the desired substitutions by using the following regular expression.

```
r = /\G[^'\n]*?(?:'[^'\n]*'[^'\n]*?)*?\K\band\b/
```

[Start your engine!](https://rubular.com/r/ECDWSOi5mp1K16)

The Ruby code needed is as follows.

```
str = "an and with 'one' word and 'two and three' words and end"

str.gsub(r, '&')
  #=> "an & with 'one' word & 'two and three' words & end"
```

[Ruby code tester](http://tpcg.io/hRHR5vV9)

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations. Essentially, the regex asserts that `"and"` follows an even number of single quotes since the previous match, or an even number of single quotes from the beginning of the string if it is the first match.

```
\G          : asserts position at the end of the previous match
              or the start of the string for the first match
[^'\n]*?    : match 0+ chars other than ' and \n, lazily
(?:         : begin capture group
  '[^'\n]*' : match ' then 0+ chars other than ' and \n then '
  [^'\n]*?  : match 0+ chars other than ' and \n, lazily
)           : end non-capture group
*?          : execute non-capture group 0+ times, lazily 
\K          : forget everything matched so far and reset start of match
\band\b/    : match 'and'
```